# Flutter IOS, CircleCI ARCHIVE FAILED after upgraded Xcode to 13.0.0

Tags: ios, flutter, circleci, xcode13

I've been deploying our Flutter application through CircleCi with Xcode 12.4.0. But, after upgrading Xcode to **13.0.0** (Not the beta version) in the `config.yml` file, the Fastlane **build_app** action doesn’t succeed anymore. It works fine locally.
I've been trying to solve the issue by taking the following actions but, nothing has worked.

- I have selected the right version of Xcode as the Logs suggest.
- I have updated Fastlane and all the Gems required for the deployment to run.
- I have updated the project to the latest Flutter version and dependencies.
- I tried [THIS SOLUTION](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56085#issuecomment-726018979) related to the Run Script from Build Phases in Xcode.
- I tried [THIS SOLUTION](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/xcode-8-3-build-timing-out/11721/7) that seems to have solved similar problems when upgrading Xcode.

These are the logs with the maximum amount of details that I have obtained. I have checked the logs from `Library/Logs/gym/` but no further details are included.

```
▸ Touching firebase_performance.framework (in target 'firebase_performance' from project 'Pods')
▸ Touching firebase_messaging.framework (in target 'firebase_messaging' from project 'Pods')
▸ Touching firebase_crashlytics.framework (in target 'firebase_crashlytics' from project 'Pods')
▸ Touching firebase_analytics.framework (in target 'firebase_analytics' from project 'Pods')
▸ Processing Pods-Runner-Info.plist
▸ Copying Pods-Runner-umbrella.h
▸ Compiling Pods-Runner-dummy.m
▸ Compiling Pods_Runner_vers.c
▸ Touching Pods_Runner.framework (in target 'Pods-Runner' from project 'Pods')
▸ Running script '[CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock'
▸ Running script 'Run Script'
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/distiller/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gxqijsvgrrorpceyqfglwnknrvli/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Development/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Runner.build/Release-Development-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
(1 failure)
[08:59:07]: Exit status: 65
[08:59:07]: 
[08:59:07]: Maybe the error shown is caused by using the wrong version of Xcode
[08:59:07]: Found multiple versions of Xcode in '/Applications/'
[08:59:07]: Make sure you selected the right version for your project
[08:59:07]: This build process was executed using '/Applications/Xcode-13.0.app'
[08:59:07]: If you want to update your Xcode path, either
[08:59:07]: 
[08:59:07]: - Specify the Xcode version in your Fastfile
[08:59:07]: ▸ xcversion(version: "8.1") # Selects Xcode 8.1.0
[08:59:07]: 
[08:59:07]: - Specify an absolute path to your Xcode installation in your Fastfile
[08:59:07]: ▸ xcode_select "/Applications/Xcode8.app"
[08:59:07]: 
[08:59:07]: - Manually update the path using
[08:59:07]: ▸ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
[08:59:07]: 

+---------------+------------------------------+
|              Build environment               |
+---------------+------------------------------+
| xcode_path    | /Applications/Xcode-13.0.app |
| gym_version   | 2.195.0                      |
| export_method | ad-hoc                       |
| sdk           | iPhoneOS15.0.sdk             |
+---------------+------------------------------+

[08:59:07]: ▸ Failed to package /Users/distiller/project.
[08:59:07]: ▸ Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
[08:59:07]: ▸ /Users/distiller/project/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.0.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
[08:59:07]: 
[08:59:07]: ⬆️  Check out the few lines of raw `xcodebuild` output above for potential hints on how to solve this error
[08:59:07]:   For the complete and more detailed error log, check the full log at:
[08:59:07]:   /Users/distiller/Library/Logs/gym/Runner-Development.log
[08:59:07]: 
[08:59:07]: Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
[08:59:07]: It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
[08:59:07]: to troubleshoot build and signing issues: https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/
[08:59:07]: Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
[08:59:07]: sure your project is set up correctly.
[08:59:07]: fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
[08:59:07]: the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
[08:59:07]: Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
[08:59:07]: 
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                                    Lane Context                                    |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM          | ios                                                    |
| PLATFORM_NAME             | ios                                                    |
| LANE_NAME                 | ios publish_alpha                                      |
| KEYCHAIN_PATH             | ~/Library/Keychains/fastlane_tmp_keychain              |
| ORIGINAL_DEFAULT_KEYCHAIN | "/Users/distiller/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db" |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

- Does anyone have any idea about why this is happening? OR is this happening to anyone as well?

Comment: I have the same problem! :( googled everything with no luck..